# How to create a dynamic title in a Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to create a Matplotlib animation where the title changes with each frame. Here's what I have so far (pretty much blindly copy/pasted from [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html)); `A` contains the data I'm plotting and `textVec` contains the titles I want to add:

```
fig = plt.figure()

textVec = ['Period ' + str(i[0]) + ' to ' + str(i[1]) + '.'
for i in sliceVec]

ims = []
for i in A:
   ims.append((ax = plt.pcolormesh(i), ))

plt.xlabel(r'$\omega$', size = 22)
plt.ylabel(r'$\gamma$', size = 22)

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=300,
   repeat_delay=1000, blit=True)
```

The above works, but how to add these titles?

Cheers

Comment: Haven't played with `ArtistAnimation`, but remember that titles are just `Text` objects, and `Text` objects are also `artist` objects.

Comment: I join you question...did you manage to work it out?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but still cost me half a day trying and trying to get an **individual title for each frame** using `animation.ArtistAnimation()`.
It's just not working.
The closest I got was by setting an annotation but it disappeared as soon as it was above the plot (somehow outside the drawn region).

What worked for me is the `animation.FuncAnimation()`
There was no data given in the initial question so I set something up.

```
# generate dummy data
data = []
for i in range(10):
    # make these smaller to increase the resolution
    dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05
    # generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
    y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-5, 5 + dy, dy),
                    slice(-5, 5 + dx, dx)]   
    z = np.cos((x*x + y*y) - i*2*np.pi/10)
    # x and y are bounds, so z should be the value *inside* those bounds.
    # Therefore, remove the last value from the z array.
    z = z[:-1, :-1]
    
    data.append((x, y, z))
    
# generate title
titles = ["frame nr {}".format(frame) for frame in range(len(data))]


def func(frame, ax, data, titles):

    ax.pcolormesh(*data[frame])
    ax.set_title(titles[frame])
    
    return ax


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

frames = range(len(data))
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames, interval=300,
                              repeat_delay=1000, blit=False,
                              fargs=(ax, data, titles))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not laying out a full solution here, but using these pointers you should be able to get what you want:

You need to include a line in the function `update_line` that should be in the python code (not in your post). This line should set the title of the figure in every iteration of this function. `plt.title()` should work fine for this purpose.

Comment: So you assume this is 'homework'? Well played ;-) (It's for a thesis.)